# Should we have an option for a user to permanently delete his account

Tags: accounts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How should I allow my members to delete their membership from my site?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1905/how-should-i-allow-my-members-to-delete-their-membership-from-my-site)

If user sign up for a website, should we have an option for him to permanently delete his account. For example if someone register for a website using other people email. the real owners of the email has no idea about this website and want to delete this account. should we allow this or simply just let the user ignore it.

Comment: ํำYeahhhh, i have -1 on my question.

Comment: If you use the search feature on this site [you would have found](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1905/how-should-i-allow-my-members-to-delete-their-membership-from-my-site) that this [question](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/5088/is-it-right-to-make-account-deletion-difficult) has [been asked](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1157/how-to-handle-account-disabling-and-enabling) in a variety of formats [numerous times](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/10329/whats-the-best-way-to-handle-deleted-user-accounts-on-a-social-app) already.

Comment: If you find you're getting questions closed or receiving downvotes then [check this guide on how to ask questions](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) which should give you some help for future questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's good to allow your users to delete their accounts. Personally I've found the option to do so to be comforting--it also increases my trust of the site or service.

> For example if someone register for a website using other people email. the real owners of the email has no idea about this website and want to delete this account.

If you anticipate this to actually happen on your site then perhaps your account creation process should include sending a confirm-your-email-address email.

Comment: It has sent the confirmation email addess, but the account still there even if he is not confirmed.

Comment: You could add some rules so that such accounts cannot be accessed after a period of time (3 days?). The site can then delete these accounts after a month.

Comment: Depending on the laws of your country, maybe you have to delete those accounts after a certain period of time. In Germany those laws are very strict, for instance. If someone sues you for this, you even have to pay a fine. I don't know whether it's the same in other countries, but that's a really big issue here.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly a confirmation email should always be used to confirm the registration if an email address is required as part of registration, thus an account should never be activated until a user has confirmed via this email.

Secondly for user which requires their account created after deletion I would ensure another confirmation email is sent to confirm this and you simply soft delete the account if they confirm also give the user the option to completely delete their account through maybe a more rigorous process including maybe a 30 day period to change their mind before their data is irrecoverable.